# How to prevent trigger firing on the detail object when master object is inserted/updated

Tags: trigger, master-detail

Hi I have 2 custom objects and have a master-detail relationship between them.

> Master : Certification Slot
>
> Detail : Certification Slot Detail

I write a trigger on Master object for a Duplicate check based on a field value `Week__c` for that object. I have a ROLL up Summary field on Parent `No_of_Booked_Slots__c`
This trigger runs in before Insert and before update and it is working fine. 
I'm facing a wierd issue which i have never come across. 
When i try to insert or edit on the detail record, this trigger is running.

Note: I'm not updating any field on the Detail object based on this trigger.

TRIGGER HANDLER CLASS:

```
public with sharing class CI_CertificationSlotTriggerHandler{


    public static void CertificationSlotInsert(list<Certification_Slot__c> newSlotList){

        Map<Id, Certification_Slot__c> existingslotMap = new Map<Id, Certification_Slot__c>([Select Id,Booking_Date__c,Week_Interval__c,Week__c from Certification_Slot__c where (Week__c != null OR Week__c != '')]);

        for(Certification_Slot__c cNew : newSlotList){
            cNew.Week__c = String.valueOf(cNew.Booking_Date__c.toStartofWeek()).split(' ')[0] + ' TO ' + String.valueOf((cNew.Booking_Date__c.toStartofWeek()).addDays(6)).split(' ')[0];
            system.debug('WEEK VALUE***'+cNew.Week__c);
            if(!existingslotMap.isEmpty()){
                if(cNew.Week__c == existingslotMap.get(cNew.Id).Week__c || cNew.Booking_Date__c == existingslotMap.get(cNew.Id).Booking_Date__c){
                    cNew.addError('You cannot create a duplicate record for the same week');
                }
            }        
        }        

    }

    public static void CertificationSlotUpdate(list<Certification_Slot__c> updSlotList){
        Map<Id, Certification_Slot__c> existingslotMap = new Map<Id, Certification_Slot__c>([Select Id,Booking_Date__c,Week_Interval__c,Week__c from Certification_Slot__c where (Week__c != null OR Week__c != '')]);

        for(Certification_Slot__c cNew : updSlotList){
            cNew.Week__c = String.valueOf(cNew.Booking_Date__c.toStartofWeek()).split(' ')[0] + ' TO ' + String.valueOf((cNew.Booking_Date__c.toStartofWeek()).addDays(6)).split(' ')[0];
            system.debug('WEEK VALUE***'+cNew.Week__c);
            if(cNew.Week__c == existingslotMap.get(cNew.Id).Week__c || cNew.Booking_Date__c == existingslotMap.get(cNew.Id).Booking_Date__c){
                cNew.addError('You cannot create a duplicate record for the same week');
            }        
        }        

    }

}
```

TRIGGER:

```
trigger CI_CertificationSlotTrigger on Certification_Slot__c (before insert, before update) {

    if (trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert) {
        CI_CertificationSlotTriggerHandler.CertificationSlotInsert(trigger.new);
    }

    if (trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate) {
        CI_CertificationSlotTriggerHandler.CertificationSlotUpdate(trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to review the [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) document. Here, they explain:

> If the record contains a roll-up summary field or is part of a cross-object workflow, performs calculations and updates the roll-up summary field in the parent record. Parent record goes through save procedure.

In other words, because you have a summary rollup field, the parent automatically goes through the entire save process *automatically*. This includes triggers, because the parent could fail to save because of `SObject.addError` or validation rules, and the parent also needs to maintain its consistent state, which may include updating other records as well.

Answer (score 0):

i think in this case Salesforce prevent user from edit child record and if you update child record then parent record also get calculated as stated in [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en).

> Salesforce prevents users from saving a record if it invalidates a
> related record. For example, a master record has a validation rule
> that requires the roll-up summary field value to be greater than 100.
> If the user’s change to a related child record would put the value
> over 100, the user can’t save the record

So i think when you update child record SF also recalculate Roll summary field which cause this trigger to run. There is also very good chances of **Workflow** which may be cause of this behavior. Just check above condition and see if it helps.